# Let the search find questions by ID

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, questions

Just searched for '1955211' in the SO search field.

Expected output: include the question/answer with ID '1955211' in the search results. If the search result set is a single question/answer, redirect to that (I seem to remember, that is already the case).

Actual output: the 'no results' page showed up.

How to fix: If the search term is /^[0-9]+$/ (or whatever a valid question/answer ID is), look up the ID database and include results with the queried ID.

Complicacies: May provide results that are not (at first sight) correlated to the search query, e.g., when searching for 127001 or 123456.

Problems steming from complicacies: If someone can't distinguish between the different result types, he should perhaps re-consider giving answers on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already exists. Searching for a specific question ID will take you to that question.

Proof? Try searching for "43410" right now.

This does not work for answers, however.

Comment: OK, I mixed up #1955211 (the answer) and #1955112 (the question). However, if you could expand this medium-term to include answers as well, it would be really cool.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can already go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955211 without doing any search, it's not clear to me that giving that as a search result for numbers would be useful. If I'm searching for a number, maybe I just want it to appear in the question/answer content.

Comment: And `/questions/XXX` even works for answer IDs---you get an HTTP redirect.

Comment: But you can't go to /questions/XXX on *NIX with a middle click on your mouse, when you selected the ID in question. However, it would be simple as nothing to paste it in the search field. That's just one use case that comes to my mind.

Comment: Someone should write one of these fancy scripts that people who know about internet programming (black magic to me) create, which prompts you for the id and gets you there.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice, if I could search `:1955211 some texts` (with colon in front of question id), especially when I want to search on a question with hundreds of answers.

Comment: +1 Based on what's allowed in search now, 'Question:n' would probably be preferred, as someone may actually want to search for ':whatever'.

Comment: It's possible now to search a question's answers. For example `inquestion:43410` searches the answers on this question (as well as the question itself).