# What should be done with the feature that redirects searches for numbers to the question with that ID?

Tags: discussion, search, redirection, post-id

Stack Exchange sites have a little-known feature: if you type in a number of four or more digits into the search box, and the number happens to be the ID of a non-deleted question (not answer), you will be [redirected to the question with that ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236709/inconsistent-behavior-when-typing-a-number-into-the-search-field?noredirect=1&lq=1).

This feature has been in place [since 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254/377214). Attitudes towards the feature have changed quite a bit over the years, as indicated by a [2010 feature request to add this redirection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43410/let-the-search-find-questions-by-id?noredirect=1&lq=1) (it already existed), versus an employee commenting in 2017 that this is a "[useless feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303597/under-what-specific-cases-does-searching-for-a-number-redirect-to-the-question-w?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment987095_303597)".

Personally, I find this feature a bit irksome. For instance, searching for "1040" on Personal Finance and Money, I (as an American) expect to be searching for questions about the income tax form 1040, but I'm redirected to [money.stackexchange.com/questions/1040](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1040). Similarly, when searching for "3000" here on MSE, I was expecting for it to provide me some search results to lead me to [Anyone with a "visited: 3000 days, 3000 consecutive" in his/her profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-3333-days-3333-consecutive-in-his-her-profile) (before its title was edited), not to go to [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3000).

Plus, the vast majority of users [do not have the ID of a question memorized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183230/377214) (10k-only).

What should be done with this feature? Would you support the feature request from 2010, or the comment from 2017?

Answer (score 7):

I ended up clicking through a series of duplicates until I got to [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/search-with-number-like-401-will-take-you-to-a-question) with an answer that says you can put the number inside quotes to search for the number rather than the ID:

> [Search] 1040

This gives you the question with ID 1040.

> [Search] "1040"

This gives you questions relating to taxes. (And now this question.)

Getting an ID result is interesting. I don't know how useful it is, but it's kind of cool. At least with knowing the trick to bypass it.

However, the feature does seem to hijack common sense.

If it's to be kept, it might make more sense to use it along with a documented search phrase:

> [Search] id:1040

Comment: There’s already a way to search by id though: `inquestion:1040`, and you can also use `is:q` to filter out the question’s answers.

Comment: @laurel I've always used that to search for *text* in a question—not for the ID of a question. In fact, when I use `inquestion:1040`, I don't get ID 1040. I get no hits.

Comment: If you’re searching on this site, question number 1040 seems to have been migrated to meta server fault and the original was deleted. I had no problem when searching for questions that actually still exist on the site.

Comment: @laurel Fair enough (and oddly coincidental). But `inquestion` is not used to *only* search for a question ID.  I went to https://movies.stackexchange.com/. There, `inquestion:1991` results only in the question with that ID but `inquestion:"1991"` results in hits with questions that have that text. So, `inquestion` exhibits the same multipurpose function as just putting in a number and nothing else into the search box. It would be nice if none of the searches went to the question with the ID *except for* a search function used specifically for that purpose and nothing else.

Comment: I agree with the search prefix. I would assume searching for a number in the text is the more common option, searching for an ID is more of an exception. Therefore it would make more sense IMHO to require extra keystrokes for the ID search (_id:_) rather than for the number search (_””_).

Comment: Being able to use the search field to locate an answer by ID (versus forcing users to type a well-structured URL) has inherent value when it comes to sharing: consider the lack of copy-and-paste IRL. That said, the *magic* associated with the four-character minimum is distasteful. I would support eliminating that magic and instead return the question with matching ID as the top result for any number searched, but *also* include "normal" results (e.g. as per quoted numbers). I also like the `id:` prefix idea.

Comment: @Laurel Nobody expects the Searching Inquestion!