# Search by permalink number

Tags: feature-request, android-app, search

When I put a question ID into the search box of any site on Stack Exchange, I'm taken right away to that question, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=326607

However, this feature does not exist in the android app. When I input a permalink question ID number as the query, I am observing no results.

I get why that might not work, but feel that it really should. This app is a great resource but the inability to enter a URL or search by ID number hampers its usefulness.. might as well just use my phone's browser. :/

Comment: "might as well just use my phone's browser" - welcome to the club.

Comment: FYI: there is a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314058/what-should-be-done-with-the-feature-that-redirects-searches-for-numbers-to-the) on whether this feature should also be removed from the website.

Comment: The app is mostly useless by now, and falling apart due to lack of development and maintenance. Such a "bonus" feature is really far fetched. :(

Comment: Hmm ... It seems that I never used to search post by id, neither on web, nor in app. User id - often, post id - just today after seeing this post.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard for key edits

Comment: And thanks @SonictheWizardWerehog for important additional context